# Restriction of type parameter in method

Tags: java, generics

## Given 3 classes:

```
class Fruit implements Comparable<Fruit> {

    private final int weigth;

    public Fruit(int weight) {
        this.weigth = weight;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Fruit other) {
        return Integer.compare(this.weigth, other.weigth);
    }

    public int getWeigth() {
        return this.weigth;
    }

}

class Apple extends Fruit {

    public Apple(int weight) {
        super(weight);
    }
}   

class Orange extends Fruit {

    public Orange(int weight) {
        super(weight);
    }
}
```

I need to fix a code adjusting compareTo method to not allow comparing different **Types** of **Fruit**.

I understand that currently **Apple** and **Orange** have superclass Fruit which can hold a reference value to both subclasses. I cannot figure out how to correctly implement **generics** to fix the problem.

The **compareTo** method should show a **compile-time** error if the argument does not match the object which invokes the method.

Comment: If you do not want the functionality shared/to be the same, I think it would be better to put it in the childclass instead of the parent class?

Comment: It would be simple to cause a *runtime* error by adding a `this.class == other.class` check to `compareTo()`. It would be more difficult to cause a *compile-time* error - I think the easiest thing to do would be to override `compareTo()` in each of the subclasses, and change the required argument's type to the respective subclass.

Comment: Can an Apple compare to an Orange?

Comment: @Loc it could by calories for example

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public abstract class Fruit<F extends Fruit<F>> implements Comparable<F> {
    public int compareTo(F other) {
        ...
    }
}

public final class Apple extends Fruit<Apple> {
    // not needed to actually write the compareTo method, it'll just work.
}
```

Comment: @zwitserloot Thanks, so, if I understand correctly.

Class Fruit has type parameter - **F extends Fruit<F>**

where

**F** - a subclass of class Fruit<F> 

Basically, an instance of  **Fruit**  cannot be created without setting a specific **Type** which is bound to **Fruit**, it should be its subclass.

In the above example, the one correction I should made is to adjust modifier for 

  `private final int weigth`;

It gives an access modifier error.